# TortoiseGit - representing branches in a tree - visual issue

Tags: git, tortoisegit

*This is a little hard to explain with text, but I'll do my best, and you try to keep up; if something isn't clear at first, don't hesitate to ask, and I'll try to clarify.*

When TortoiseGit has one branch it looks approximately like this:

```
o
|
o <-- a commit sign
|
x
```

When I split my work into a new branch, it looks like this:

```
o
|
o--o
|
x
```

when I split, from the master to another new branch it looks like this:

```
o--o
|
o--o
|
x
```

*Is there a way for every new branch that I make, and work on, to have its own "line" ... what I mean:*

```
o-----o
|
o--o
|
x
```

so they don't "vertically overlap". So that every branch, has its own vertical line I can follow (for some reason this looks rather confusing to me, the way it's done now).
Do any other Git clients for Windows do this differently ?

Comment: Have you tried Git Extensions? http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/

Comment: @Steve - yes!! that looks exactly like I'd like it to be ... unfortunatelly, no, haven't had the chance to try git extensions yet. At the moment I'm learning the ropes of TortoiseGit (I'm a Git newbie). Do you perchance know if any git clients that "plugin" into windows explorer offer the same visual representation ?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm a Git newbie myself, having just got a server running on Windows, a pain and I'm so far using the command line until I get the hang of things.  If you're on Windows, I'm not sure if TG and Git Extensions can co-exist.  There's also the default Git GUI - right click on directory and there should be a Git GUI here option.  Looks like this: http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/v/o/vorotylo/git-gui.png

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit includes a Revision Graph which might be what you are looking for (it doesn't display single commits, but all branches). It can be started from the context menu of folders.

[image: TortoiseGit revision graph]